# Print list of strings in Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this list of strings:

```
final List<String> details;
```

I want to use Text widget to print strings in list, thats how i did:

```
List<Product> products = [details: [
  '7 ounces',
  'Pack of 200 grams',
  'Golden roasted' 'Nicely packed in its original Nescafe factory'
],],
```

used Text widget:

```
Text( products.details[0], ),
```

This is printing only string at index 0.

can somebody help ?

Comment: How do you want to print it?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to want the list to be represented as a string, you can just format it using the `join()` method.

In your case,

```
products.details.join(' ')
```

**Output:**  7 ounces Pack of 200 grams Golden roasted Nicely packed in its original Nescafe factory

You can use any delimiter in the parameter of `join` which is inserted between every string item.

Further Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/join.html

Answer (score 3):

Use listView.builder,

```
ListView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  itemCount: products.details.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Text( products.details[index]);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Text(products.details.toString())
```

or

```
 Text(products.toString())
```

Comment: I tried it already and showing me like this : [7 ounces, Pack of 200 grams, Golden roasted, Nicely packed in its original Nescafe factory] .. but i want all strings without brackets.

Comment: String v = Value;

              v = v.replaceAll("[", "");

              v = v.replaceAll("]", "");

Comment: showing this error: The method 'replaceAll' isn't defined for the type 'List'.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of items, you can just use this option:

```
Text( '${products.details[0] ${products.details[1] ${products.details[2]}');
```

Or, you could create a new class and override the `toString()` method. Something like this:

```
class MyProducts {

  List<Product> products = [details: [
    '7 ounces',
    'Pack of 200 grams',
    'Golden roasted' 'Nicely packed in its original Nescafe factory'
  ],];

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '${products.details[0] ${products.details[1] ${products.details[2]}'
  }
}
```

And use it:

```
MyProducts myProducts = MyProducts();
Text( myProduct.toString() );
```